# TypeError: The plugin "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs" didn't export a Plugin instance

Tags: babeljs

I faced a problem that my existing code stopped working, and I can't get what's the reason for that problem, I have pretty simple program that transpiles ES6 code:

```
TypeError: The plugin "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs" didn't export a Plugin instance
    at PluginManager.validate (C:\Epam\dhl-ewf\cq\dhl-view\src\main\content\jcr_root\etc\clientlibs\dhl\global\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\plugin-manager.js:164:13)
    at PluginManager.add (C:\Epam\dhl-ewf\cq\dhl-view\src\main\content\jcr_root\etc\clientlibs\dhl\global\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\plugin-manager.js:213:10)
    at File.buildTransformers (C:\Epam\dhl-ewf\cq\dhl-view\src\main\content\jcr_root\etc\clientlibs\dhl\global\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:237:21)
    at new File (C:\Epam\dhl-ewf\cq\dhl-view\src\main\content\jcr_root\etc\clientlibs\dhl\global\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:139:10)
    at Pipeline.transform (C:\Epam\dhl-ewf\cq\dhl-view\src\main\content\jcr_root\etc\clientlibs\dhl\global\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:164:16)
    at load (C:\Epam\dhl-ewf\cq\dhl-view\src\main\content\jcr_root\etc\clientlibs\dhl\global\Es6\index.js:63:26)
    at Object.jsdom.env.done (C:\Epam\dhl-ewf\cq\dhl-view\src\main\content\jcr_root\etc\clientlibs\dhl\global\Es6\index.js:216:5)
    at C:\Epam\dhl-ewf\cq\dhl-view\src\main\content\jcr_root\etc\clientlibs\dhl\global\Es6\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom.js:271:18
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:433:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:362:13)
```

My code is not representative it stops at the following line:

```
    let transpiled = babel.transform(source, {
        "plugins": [
            'transform-es2015-modules-commonjs',
            'transform-es2015-destructuring',
            'transform-es2015-parameters',
            'transform-es2015-spread'
        ] });
```

What may be the problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use Babel 6 plugins with Babel 5.

Comment: How to fix the issue, sir? I got the same problem but I don't know how to fix. Thanks

Comment: @jack.pop Either upgrade Babel, or downgrade your plugin (if there is one for Babel 5).